# Determining if an input is a number

Tags: python

How do I find out if my user's input is a number?

```
input = raw_input()

if input = "NUMBER":
    do this
else:
    do this
```

What is "NUMBER" in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "number".  If any floating point number is fine, you can use

```
s = raw_input()
try:
    x = float(s)
except ValueError:
    # no number
else:
    # number
```

Comment: If you want to also support complex numbers, use `complex()`. For simple ints `int()` should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

If you're testing for integers you can use the isdigit function:

```
x = "0042"

x.isdigit()
```

True

Comment: Sadly enough, `x = "0.5"; x.isdigit() == False`. Not suitable for floats.

Comment: Also doesn't work for negative numbers and bases other than 10.

Answer (score 0):

string = raw_input('please enter a number:')

Checking if a character is a digit is easy once you realize that characters are just ASCII code numbers. The character '0' is ASCII code 48 and the character '9' is ASCII code 57. '1'-'8' are in between. So you can check if a particular character is a digit by writing:

> validNumber=False
>
> while not validNumber:
>
> string = raw_input('please enter a number:')
>
> i=0
>
> validNumber=True
>
> while i
>
> if not (string[i]>='0' and string[i]<='9'):
>
> validNumber=False
>
> print 'You entered an invalid number. Please try again'
>
> break
>
> i=i+1

Answer (score 0):

An answer I found elsewhere on StackOverflow [I forget where] gave the following code for checking if something was a number:

```
#This checks to see if input is a number
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```